# How do you print elements that are less than a variable from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi so Im fairly new to python and an assignment require me to print elements that are less than a variable from a numpy array.

I made a 20x10 numpy array of random integers between -5 and 50

```
x = np.random.randint (-5, 50, (20, 10))
x

array([[17, 23, 15, 13, -1, 17, 30, 14,  2,  3],
   [ 8,  0, -5,  3, 10, 10, 48,  6, -1, 34],
   [23, 40, 21,  5, 47, 41, 44, 22, 46, 30],
   [36, 13, 48, 29, 46, 25, 48, 38, 13, 40],
   [18, -4,  1, 37, 48, 43, 25, 11, 21, 30],
   [44, 37,  4, 39,  8,  1, 33, 34,  3,  8],
   [ 2, 11, 17, 10, 20,  3, 30,  1, 12,  2],
   [15, 20, -3, 11, 45, 40, 18, 19, -1, 31],
   [39, 44, 18, 25, 49, 20, 15, 28, 32, 18],
   [22, 24, 28, 46, 48, 46, 17, 49,  2, 36],
   [44,  4, 49, -5, 14, 31, 12, 15, 48, 43],
   [-2, 37, -4, 15, 31, -1, 11, 43, 42,  5],
   [40, 35, 25, 22, 38, 26, 15,  1,  4, 22],
   [42, 30, 14,  7, 13, 44,  5, 29, 28, 38],
   [-2,  7, 31, -4, 44, -5, 34, 19, 31, 30],
   [ 0,  1, -2, 29, 35, 28, 23, -1, 21, 27],
   [40, 46,  4, 48,  0, 28,  2, 25,  3, 49],
   [15,  2, -2, 16, 22, 39, -2, 33, 15,  2],
   [14, 26, -5,  0, 22, 38, 25,  4, 14,  2],
   [16, 32, 23,  3, 38, 41, -5, 35, 46, 33]])
```

above is the result. Now i want to print the number of elements that are less than 5 in each row.

I managed to do this

```
print (x[0, :] < 5)

[False False False False  True False False False  True  True]
```

the result is as shown above  but what i wanted was for it to show the number of elements that is less than 5. I wanted for it to give me 3 since there are 3 elements.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your boolean mask to index the array and then count the elements. Alternatively, you can use `numpy.where()`. Similar to your approach, it will give you a boolean mask where a certain condition is met.

For your example:

```
indices = numpy.where(x < 3)
values_greater_than_3 = x[indices]
count = len(values_greater_than_3)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use `np.sum` for arrays of type `bool` like yours. So, at first I have tried the following:

```
[np.sum(n<5) for n in x]
```

This gives me a list `[3, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2]` which is correct but the bad thing is that you need to avoid list comprehensions in `numpy` actions.  Here is the best way to do this in `numpy`:

```
np.sum(x<5, axis=1)
```

This command makes `bool` array out of `x` and then calculates `True` values for each row along y axis (axis number 1)

Comment: Thank you so much man this is the answer that I am looking for

Comment: Hi, if you dont mind me asking again. why does this code that you give

np.sum(x<5, axis=1)

works perfectly but when i try to do 

np.sum ((x>=0) and (x<=50), axis=1)

it gives me the error?

Comment: `x<5` is a mask array. It contains `True`s and `False`s. Such kind of arrays doesn't support `and` operator unlike bools `True` and `False`. Try to use `arr1 & arr2` or `np.logical_and(arr1, arr2)` instead.